# Alert that a similar data is already entered

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out a way to detect whether a similar input is entered into mysql database before or not.
I am not saying duplicate entry no similar but not exact, the thing is that when data entry staff need to enter a name the pronunciation of the name might be entered differently from one to another so I need a way so that my php code detects whether an entry similar to the one being entered is already input and warn the staff to double check if it is the same name or not

Comment: you need to write sql and query against your db.

Comment: This has the potential to be a massively complicated problem.

Comment: If the names have an english pronunciation you might be able use [SOUNDEX(str)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex), for other languages you would need to calculate the value outside of mysql before inserting or querying. But this approach could also fail depending on the actual usecase.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with mysql alone but needs to be handled by your code. So before inserting any data into a table, a query needs to be formulated and executed to find potential *similar* data. The definition what counts as similar depends strongly on your business needs.

Fuzzy search is not the strength of MySQL by you might get away with one or several `like` conditions. Searches for variations to a Levenshtein distance of two — maybe three — might be done by calculating possible variations with wildcard placeholders and combine them into one query. This approach is described in more detail by [Gordon Lesti](https://gordonlesti.com/fuzzy-fulltext-search-with-mysql/). Depending on the complexity of those queries and the traffic on a system, this has grate potential to bring a mysql instance down quite easily.

If performance is an issue, a search engine like Elasticsearch might get helpful. When inserting data into MySQL, this data would also be added as a document to Elasticsearch. This would allow to search for similar records by using the fuzzy search capabilities of Elasticsearch which is by far more performant than MySQL.

If the transactional safety of MySQL is not a requirement for the application, one might also opt to replace MySQL with Elasticsearch and use Elasticsearch not only for searching but also for persistency.

Comment: This can be done by mysql alone. Depending on how it should be handled it could be by wrapping the insert in a function, an insert trigger, or by dissociating the insert and the lookup comparison. The lookup comparison could be implemented using soundex (out of the box) or a more complex user defined phoneme algorithm. Levenstein is completely the wrong algorithm.

Comment: Agreed, I have not considered using hooks. But I definitely would not agree that Levenstein is completely wrong. The choice of algorithm depends on your definition of _similar_. If you are looking for words which sound different when pronounce, yes then soundex is a good choice. If you intend to find similar words containing typos, Levenstein is a valid choice.